# avoid double refresh of plot in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny plot I am trying to highlight points matching a clicked point (based on nearPoints() and click).

It sort of works.  However, the reactive parts of the shiny app are refreshed twice and the second iteration seems to clear the clicked information.

How can I avoid the second refresh of the app?

Here is the MWE:

```
library("Cairo")
library("ggplot2")
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    titlePanel('Phenotype Plots')
  ),

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("plotui")
  ),

  hr(),

  fluidRow(

    wellPanel(
      h4("Selected"),
      tableOutput("info_clicked")
      ##dataTableOutput("info_clicked") ## overkill here
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  selected_line <-  reactive({
    nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot_click,
               maxpoints = 1,
               addDist = TRUE)
  })

  output$plotui <- renderUI({
      plotOutput("plot", height=600,
        click = "plot_click"
      )
    })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    p <- ggplot(mtcars) +
      facet_grid(am ~ cyl) +
      theme_bw() +
      geom_point(aes(x=wt, y=mpg))

    sline <- selected_line()
    if (nrow(sline) > 0) {
      p <- p +
        geom_point(aes(x=wt, y=mpg),
                   data=mtcars[mtcars$gear == sline$gear,],
                   colour="darkred",
                   size=1)
    }

    p

  })

  ##output$info_clicked <- renderDataTable({
  output$info_clicked <- renderTable({
    res <- selected_line()
    ## datatable(res)
    res
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally(!) found a workaround for avoiding double refresh on click in Shiny: capture click to a `reactiveValue()`, using the `observeEvent()`. Seemingly works on my project, and for your MWE, too. See updated code section below.

```
library("Cairo")
library("ggplot2")
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    titlePanel('Phenotype Plots')
  ),

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("plotui")
  ),

  hr(),

  fluidRow(

    wellPanel(
      h4("Selected"),
      tableOutput("info_clicked")
      ##dataTableOutput("info_clicked") ## overkill here
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ## CHANGE HERE
  ## Set up buffert, to keep the click.  
  click_saved <- reactiveValues(singleclick = NULL)

  ## CHANGE HERE
  ## Save the click, once it occurs.
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$plot_click, handlerExpr = { click_saved$singleclick <- input$plot_click })


  ## CHANGE HERE  
  selected_line <-  reactive({
    nearPoints(mtcars, click_saved$singleclick, ## changed from "input$plot_click" to saved click.
               maxpoints = 1,
               addDist = TRUE)
  })

  output$plotui <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("plot", height=600,
               click = "plot_click"
    )
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    p <- ggplot(mtcars) +
      facet_grid(am ~ cyl) +
      theme_bw() +
      geom_point(aes(x=wt, y=mpg))

    sline <- selected_line()
    if (nrow(sline) > 0) {
      p <- p +
        geom_point(aes(x=wt, y=mpg),
                   data=mtcars[mtcars$gear == sline$gear,],
                   colour="darkred",
                   size=1)
    }

    p

  })

  ##output$info_clicked <- renderDataTable({
  output$info_clicked <- renderTable({
    res <- selected_line()
    ## datatable(res)
    res
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Works like a charm -- even in my 'real' application.

Comment: Dude. This problem has been blocking me for like 3 days! Thanks for the posted solution. I'm still not 100% sure why it works (anyone have an explanation?)... But it does. +1